# ErrnoException: statvfs failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)

Tags: android, android-external-storage

In my app, I am getting info about device storage (total and free space) using [StatFs](http://developer.android.com/intl/pt-br/reference/android/os/StatFs.html) class.

It is initialized this way:

```
StatFs stat = new StatFs(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath());
```

This app has a bug reporting tool that reports the follwoing error in the previous piece of code:

> **android.system.ErrnoException**
>
> Posix.java line -2 in Posix.statvfs()
>
> statvfs failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)

I've found little info about this error, like [here](https://chrisolin.com/blog/the-dreaded-android-libcore-bug-from-hell-that-i-wasnt-actually-experiencing-it-was-really-selinux/) and [here](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2744358)

The documentation about [ErrnoException](http://developer.android.com/intl/pt-br/reference/android/system/ErrnoException.html) says: A checked exception thrown when Os methods fail.

Someone else has faced this issue?

Comment: Possibly this is one of the few devices that has removable external storage, and the card is removed. Are you checking whether external storage is mounted first?

Comment: @CommonsWare no, I am not doing this checking. Really great tip. Thank you.

Comment: @CommonsWare but if the primary shared/external storage directory (returned by getExternalStorageDirectory) is not mounted, how can I get info about the device storage? Do I have to assume the secondary storage (available through getExternalFilesDirs, getExternalCacheDirs, and getExternalMediaDirs)? Or I am not able to get this info?

Comment: "how can I get info about the device storage?" -- you cannot get details of media that does not exist (and, from your standpoint, media that is not mounted does not exist). You can learn about internal storage via `getFilesDir()`. You can see if removable storage exists via those methods you cited.

Comment: @androidevil did you solve the issue? I have the same problem.

Comment: I am facing this issue in my device info and most of the crashes are coming from Samsung devices Android 10